# Difference between two year-extracting codes

Tags: vba, excel

I have two codes that I have written/got help from other people and just wondering if these two codes can be combined into single code that does a lot of work for me.. First code I have is

---

```
Private Sub extractYears()

    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, ur As Range, colW As Long, colV As Long

    Set ur = cFinal.UsedRange               '4th sheet
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ur) > 0 Then
        colW = colNum("Q")
        colV = colNum("R")
        If 1 Then
            arr = ur
            For i = 2 To getMaxCell(ur).Row     'each "row"
                If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 0 Then arr(i, colW) = Format(arr(i, colW), "yyyy")
                If Len(arr(i, colV)) > 0 Then arr(i, colV) = Format(arr(i, colV), "yyyy")
            Next
            ur = arr
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

and the other one is

---

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To lastRow
   If IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value) And Not IsEmpty(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value) Then
      With wsFinal
         .Cells(i, "Q").Value = Year(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value)
      End With
   End If
Next i

Dim j As Long
For j = 2 To lastRow
   If IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value) And Not IsEmpty(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value) Then
      With wsFinal
         .Cells(j, "R").Value = Year(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value)
      End With
    End If
Next j
```

---

Whenever I get a data from external source, these two columns (Q) and (R) are the most problematic elements because the whole column sometimes only contain years(Not Date formatted), and sometimes dates formatted as date, and possibly both types of non-date formatted years and date formatted dates in the same column.

Every time a data comes in I have to check the type of column Q and R and if they consists of only the years, then I would use the second set of code and extractYears when the column only has full date format. I am not sure why using either one for all types won't work. It would just spit out numbers that I believe, are the number of days that have passed since 1905.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem I have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified extractYears()

---

```
Private Sub extractYears()

    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, ur As Range, colW As Long, colV As Long

    Set ur = cFinal.UsedRange                   '3rd sheet

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ur) > 0 Then

        colW = colNum("W")
        colV = colNum("V")

        arr = ur                                'transfer sheet data to memory

        For i = 2 To getMaxCell(ur).Row         'each "row"

            If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 0 Then       'if not empty
                If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 4 Then   'if it's full date (longer than 4 digits)
                    arr(i, colW) = Format(arr(i, colW), "yyyy") 'extract the year part
                End If
            End If                              'if it contains 4 digit year leave it as is

            If Len(arr(i, colV)) > 0 Then       'the same logic applied for colV
                If Len(arr(i, colV)) > 4 Then
                    arr(i, colV) = Format(arr(i, colV), "yyyy")
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ur = arr                                'transfer memory data back to sheet

    End If
End Sub
```

---

It will work with dates like this:

```
08/03/2007  -> 2007
05/24/2006  -> 2006
2007        -> 2007
2012        -> 2012
```

---

For both columns I applied an extra condition: `If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 4 Then`

You can apply it to any other column that contains both: full dates, or years only (4 digits)

Notes for your second method:

- try not to iterate over every cell in the column as it decreases performance considerable

  - copy the entire column with data (`.UsedRange.Column`) to a variant array and loop on that
  - functions `IsDate(val)` and `IsEmpty(val)` work the same way
  - function `Len(val) > 0` is faster than `IsEmpty(val)`
- if both columns end on the same row, you don't need to perform 2 loops for each column

  - get the last row for one of them and modify both columns at the same time
  - (the same way as in the first function)